# Outlook Automation Exception

Tags: c#, exception, outlook, office-interop

I am using the [the sample code provided by microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310263) to automate Outlook.
But i get an Exception: HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT) when i try to add the Recipient.
My Envoirement:

- VS2010
- Outlook 2007
- WinXP 32bit
- Domain

Any ideas what is going wrong? Do i require any special permissions?

Regards

Comment: COM error codes is something I do *not* miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use Redemption or just the .To Property...